# Do AWS IAM user access keys need to be regenerated whenever permissions are changed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Suppose a user has Access Keys. Do I need to regenerate the user's Access Keys whenever I change permissions for that user?

Example: If a user has access to EC2 only and now I add RDS access, do I need to regenerate the AWS keys for that user so that the new permissions can used via the keys?

Answer (score 6):

No, the keys can stay the same, you just change what the keys can do. They keys don't contain information about what they can do, they contain information to identify someone/something.

Once a user uses the keys to gain access, AWS will decide what that person/machine can do based on the rules you setup - can can change those rules at anytime and the keys that are already given out will obey those new rules.